# The use of modulo in the mathematical induction proof of $7^{2n}-9$ being divisible by 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I tried proving that $7^{2n}-9$ is divisible by 2 in the following way:

Base case: When $n=1$,

$$7^{2}-9\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\,2)$$

Induction step: Assume $n=k$,

$$7^{2k}-9\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\,2)$$

We want to prove that it is true for $n=k+1$,

$$7^{2(k+1)}-9=7^{2k+2}-9=49\cdot7^{2k}-9$$

$$=49\cdot7^{2k}-9=49\cdot[0\;(\text{mod}\,2)+9]-9.$$

Since I couldn't continue, I used the following instead:

Induction step: Assume $n=k$,

$$7^{2k}-9=2a$$

For $n=k+1$,

$$7^{2(k+1)}-9=7^{2k+2}-9=49\cdot7^{2k}-9$$

$$=49\cdot7^{2k}-9=49\cdot(2a+9)-9=2(49a+216)=2b.$$

Can anyone show me how to prove this by modulo instead?

Comment: Do you need necessarily to use induction? If not simply observe that 
$$7^{2n}-9\equiv (1)^{2n}-1\equiv 0 \mod 2$$

Comment: @ gimusi: Yes, but if you have another alternative, I 'll also appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another proof:

$7^{2n}-9 \pmod 2$ is the difference of two squares — $(7^n+9)(7^n-9)$. Both brackets are even (prove it!), so the original expression is not just even, it is divisible by $4$ (Robert Z)!

Comment: @ Toby Mak: I appreciate your sound idea! I am grateful!

Comment: If you know that the sum and the difference of two odd numbers is even there is no need to factor $7^{2n}-9$ (which is the difference of two odd numbers).  On the other hand the factorization $(7^n+9)(7^n-9)$ implies that $7^{2n}-9$ is divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Following your approach, note that in the inductive step,
$$7^{2(k+1)}-9=49\cdot7^{2k}-9=49\underbrace{(7^{2k}-9)}_{\equiv 0 \pmod{2}}+\underbrace{(49-1)}_{\equiv 0 \pmod{2}}\cdot9\equiv 0 \pmod{2}.$$

P.S. Instead of induction, a straightforward proof follows from the basic facts that:

1) the product of two odd numbers is odd (so $7^{2n}$ is odd);

2) the difference of two odd numbers is even (so $7^{2n}-9$ is even).

Comment: @ Robert Z: I love your kind of proof!

Comment: @Mike Actually, induction is not the best way to show that $7^{2n}-9$ is even. See my P.S.

Comment: @ @ Robert Z: Thank you very much for this P.S.!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative simply observe that

$$7^{2n}-9\equiv (1)^{2n}-1\equiv 0 \mod 2$$

Comment: @ gimusi: I appreciate the way you promptly and cogently answer questions! Thank you!

Comment: Yes indeed in this way is quite straightforward!